# Unable to start Artifactory on a clean Debian 10.12 install

Tags: tomcat, debian, artifactory, startup

after installation of jfrog-artifactory-oss 7.41.4 package on my Debian 10.12 install, i tried to start Artifactory service, but that failed with following logs:

console.log:

```
2022-07-21T10:39:22.622Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryManage.sh:90       ] [main] - Starting Artifactory tomcat as user artifactory...
2022-07-21T10:39:22.636Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1602       ] [main] - Checking open files and processes limits
2022-07-21T10:39:22.650Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1605       ] [main] - Current max open files is 1024
2022-07-21T10:39:22.665Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:1616       ] [main] - Current max open processes is 31788
2022-07-21T10:39:22.701Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:2969       ] [main] - System.yaml validation succeeded
2022-07-21T10:39:22.939Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3474       ] [main] - Found explicit shared.node.id in system.yaml with value : art1
2022-07-21T10:39:23.030Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3474       ] [main] - Found explicit shared.node.ip in system.yaml with value : <REDACTED>
2022-07-21T10:39:23.137Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [installerCommon.sh:3474       ] [main] - Found explicit shared.node.name in system.yaml with value : <REDACTED>
2022-07-21T10:39:23.432Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [artifactoryCommon.sh:221      ] [main] - Using Tomcat template to generate : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/server.xml
2022-07-21T10:39:23.569Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.port||8081} to default value : 8081
2022-07-21T10:39:23.665Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.sendReasonPhrase||false} to default value : false
2022-07-21T10:39:23.768Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.relaxedPathChars||_SQUARE_BRACKETS_} to default value : _SQUARE_BRACKETS_
2022-07-21T10:39:23.860Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.relaxedQueryChars||_SQUARE_BRACKETS_} to default value : _SQUARE_BRACKETS_
2022-07-21T10:39:23.947Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||200} to default value : 200
2022-07-21T10:39:24.121Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.port||8091} to default value : 8091
2022-07-21T10:39:24.216Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.maxThreads||5} to default value : 5
2022-07-21T10:39:24.307Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${artifactory.tomcat.maintenanceConnector.acceptCount||5} to default value : 5
2022-07-21T10:39:24.483Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.http.port||8040} to default value : 8040
2022-07-21T10:39:24.596Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.sendReasonPhrase||false} to default value : false
2022-07-21T10:39:24.707Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${access.tomcat.connector.maxThreads||50} to default value : 50
2022-07-21T10:39:24.929Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:610       ] [main] - Resolved JF_PRODUCT_HOME (/opt/jfrog/artifactory) from environment variable
2022-07-21T10:39:25.112Z [shell] [INFO ] [] [systemYamlHelper.sh:970       ] [main] - Resolved ${shared.tomcat.workDir||/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat} to default value : /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/work/artifactory/tomcat
Max number of open files: 1024
Using JF_PRODUCT_HOME: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
Using JF_ARTIFACTORY_PID: /var/run/artifactory.pid
Tomcat started.
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
2022-07-21T12:39:28.580L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init] - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"] 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.611L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init] - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091"] 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.613L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init] - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8040"] 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.624L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService] [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal] - Starting service [Catalina] 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.625L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine] [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal] - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.62-jfrog2] 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.646L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.646L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml] 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.694L [tomct] [WARNING] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - The path attribute with value [/artifactory] in deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml] has been ignored 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.693L [tomct] [WARNING] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - The path attribute with value [/access] in deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] has been ignored 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.702L [tomct] [WARNING] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored 
2022-07-21T12:39:28.703L [tomct] [WARNING] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored 
2022-07-21T10:39:30.355Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [o.a.c.h.HaNodeProperties:65   ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Artifactory is running in non-clustered mode.
2022-07-21T10:39:30.371Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [tifactoryHomeConfigListener:85] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Resolved Home: '/opt/jfrog/artifactory
2022-07-21T10:39:31.479Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [                ] [o.j.c.w.FileWatcher:146       ] [file-watcher-poller ] - Starting watch of folder configurations
2022-07-21T10:39:31.701Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [.BasicConfigurationManager:186] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Artifactory (jfrt) service initialization started. Version: 7.41.6 Revision: 74106900 PID: 4037 Home: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
2022-07-21T10:39:31.714Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [licationContextInitializer:162] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Access (jfac) service initialization started. Version: 7.48.5 Revision: 74805900 PID: 4037 Home: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
2022-07-21T10:39:31.738Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [d.c.m.ConverterManagerImpl:212] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Triggering PRE_INIT conversion, from 7.41.6 to 7.41.6
2022-07-21T10:39:31.738Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [d.c.m.ConverterManagerImpl:215] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Finished PRE_INIT conversion, current version is: 7.41.6
2022-07-21T10:39:31.739Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [d.i.DbInitializationManager:48] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Initializing DB Schema initialization manager
2022-07-21T10:39:31.740Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [.i.DbInitializationManager:176] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Database: PostgreSQL 13.7 (Debian 13.7-1.pgdg100+1). Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.3.3 Pool: postgresql
2022-07-21T10:39:31.811Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:55    ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Starting AccessApplication v7.48.5 using Java 11.0.15 on brn-mvn-test3 with PID 4037 (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-7.48.5.jar started by artifactory in /)
2022-07-21T10:39:31.812Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:686   ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - The following 1 profile is active: "production"
2022-07-21T10:39:32.206Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [d.i.DbInitializationManager:52] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - DB Schema initialization manager initialized
2022-07-21T10:39:32.215Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [SchemaInitializationManager:48] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Initializing Post-DB initialization manager
2022-07-21T10:39:32.260Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [.c.ConfigurationManagerImpl:97] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Starting file sync
2022-07-21T10:39:32.340Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [SchemaInitializationManager:51] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Post-DB initialization manager initialized
2022-07-21T10:39:32.382Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [8e080a9a70a9f86c] [o.a.m.MimeTypesReader:74      ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Converting mimetypes.xml version from 'v15' to 'v16'
2022-07-21T10:39:32.950Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [ctoryContextConfigListener:331] [art-init            ] - 
                _   _  __           _                      ____   _____ _____
     /\        | | (_)/ _|         | |                    / __ \ / ____/ ____|
    /  \   _ __| |_ _| |_ __ _  ___| |_ ___  _ __ _   _  | |  | | (___| (___
   / /\ \ | '__| __| |  _/ _` |/ __| __/ _ \| '__| | | | | |  | |\___ \\___ \
  / ____ \| |  | |_| | || (_| | (__| || (_) | |  | |_| | | |__| |____) |___) |
 /_/    \_\_|   \__|_|_| \__,_|\___|\__\___/|_|   \__, |  \____/|_____/_____/
 Version:  7.41.6                                  __/ |
 Revision: 74106900                               |___/
 Product Version:  7.41.4
 Product Revision: 74104900
 Artifactory Home: '/opt/jfrog/artifactory'
 Node ID: 'art1'

2022-07-21T10:39:33.028Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [ifactoryApplicationContext:582] [art-init            ] - Artifactory application context set to NOT READY by refresh
2022-07-21T12:39:33.080L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml] has finished in [4,433] ms 
2022-07-21T10:39:36.231Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [s.d.u.AccessJdbcHelperImpl:159] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Database: PostgreSQL 13.7 (Debian 13.7-1.pgdg100+1). Driver: PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.3.3
2022-07-21T10:39:37.006Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [alConfigurationServiceBase:185] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Configuration data wasn't found in db. Loading defaults
2022-07-21T10:39:37.274Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [alConfigurationServiceBase:125] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Current configurations are the same as the new configurations, no need for an update. No action was taken.
2022-07-21T10:39:37.569Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.h.AccessNodeIdProviderImpl:73] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Service id initialized: jfac@01g8dk0d90zfk9017ap2r00ysz
2022-07-21T10:39:37.933Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.s.s.s.ServiceConfigFactory:42] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Initializing task scheduler with 9 threads
2022-07-21T10:39:37.966Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [j.a.s.s.t.TokenServiceImpl:165] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Scheduling task for revoking expired tokens using cron expression: 9 24 0/1 * * ?
2022-07-21T10:39:38.114Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [b.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:54] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Starting JFrog Access bootstrap...
2022-07-21T10:39:38.123Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [tCertificateFileHandlerBase:68] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Initializing root certificate.
2022-07-21T10:39:38.467Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:160] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new root certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/root.crt
2022-07-21T10:39:38.469Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [tCertificateFileHandlerBase:85] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Finished initializing root certificate. Certificate source: DATABASE
2022-07-21T10:39:38.470Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [tCertificateFileHandlerBase:68] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Initializing ca certificate.
2022-07-21T10:39:38.544Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:160] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new ca certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/ca.crt
2022-07-21T10:39:38.545Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [tCertificateFileHandlerBase:85] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Finished initializing ca certificate. Certificate source: DATABASE
2022-07-21T10:39:38.750Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.s.b.AccessProjectBootstrap:75] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Finished initializing Projects Entities in 27.71 millis
2022-07-21T10:39:38.754Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.s.b.AccessProjectBootstrap:68] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Finished initializing Projects Shared Entities in 3.05 millis
2022-07-21T10:39:38.786Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.s.b.AccessProjectBootstrap:88] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Finished initializing Projects permissions in 32.16 millis
2022-07-21T10:39:38.787Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.s.b.AccessProjectBootstrap:60] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Finished initializing Projects in 67.09 millis
2022-07-21T10:39:38.788Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.a.s.s.m.MetricsServiceImpl:55] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Metrics Framework Service is disabled
2022-07-21T10:39:38.789Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.m.MetricsHelper:58        ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Initializing Metrics collector and logger for feature adoption...
2022-07-21T10:39:38.790Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.FeatureAdoptionServiceImpl:47] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - FeatureAdoption Framework service is started and is running in background...
2022-07-21T10:39:38.790Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [b.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:66] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] JFrog Access bootstrap finished.
2022-07-21T10:39:38.949Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [.a.s.JfConnectConfiguration:40] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - JFCON entitlements are disabled. jfconnect.enabled is false or undefined
2022-07-21T10:39:39.067Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [ritiesStorageServiceFactory:25] [art-init            ] - Initializing DB-based Priorities Storage Service
2022-07-21T10:39:40.004Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.a.s.s.JoinKeyAccess:172   ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Cluster join: Join key loaded successfully (from: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key)
2022-07-21T10:39:40.041Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [a.s.b.AccessServerRegistrar:70] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Starting JFrog Access registrar...
2022-07-21T10:39:40.054Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Scheduling EmailsLogCleanup task to run every 86400 seconds
2022-07-21T10:39:40.069Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Scheduling staleTokenCleanup task to run every 3600 seconds
2022-07-21T10:39:40.095Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [51d37a7970b444ef] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Scheduling loadCertificates task to run every 30 seconds
2022-07-21T10:39:40.129Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [                ] [.j.a.s.s.SystemScheduledJob:37] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Scheduling Readiness task to run with 15000 milliseconds fixed delay
2022-07-21T10:39:40.159Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [5335add08ebcd3b9] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Scheduling heartbeat task to run every 5 seconds
2022-07-21T10:39:40.163Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [                ] [.j.a.s.s.SystemScheduledJob:37] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Scheduling KeepAliveFederationServers task to run with 86400000 milliseconds fixed delay
2022-07-21T10:39:40.164Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [                ] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Scheduling federationCleanupService task to run every 1209600 seconds
2022-07-21T10:39:40.451Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [                ] [o.j.a.s.r.s.GrpcServerImpl:65 ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Starting gRPC Server on port 8045
2022-07-21T10:39:40.642Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [                ] [o.j.a.s.r.s.GrpcServerImpl:84 ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - gRPC Server started, listening on 8045
2022-07-21T10:39:41.052Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [actorySchedulerFactoryBean:729] [art-init            ] - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2022-07-21T10:39:41.094Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [ifactoryApplicationContext:289] [art-init            ] - Artifactory context starting up 52 Spring Beans...
2022-07-21T10:39:41.732Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:554 ] [art-init            ] - Initialized new service id: jfrt@01g8dk0p9wc6xr0azfwh2x1bgc
2022-07-21T10:39:41.773Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [oryAccessClientConfigStore:529] [art-init            ] - Using Access Server URL: http://localhost:8046/access source: System Config
2022-07-21T10:39:42.226Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [                ] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:61    ] [Catalina-utility-2  ] - Started AccessApplication in 11.828 seconds (JVM running for 14.34)
2022-07-21T12:39:42.273L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/access.xml] has finished in [13,627] ms 
2022-07-21T12:39:42.274L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory] - Deploying web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] 
2022-07-21T12:39:42.289L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory] - Deployment of web application directory [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [15] ms 
2022-07-21T12:39:42.292L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start] - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"] 
2022-07-21T12:39:42.309L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start] - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8091"] 
2022-07-21T12:39:42.311L [tomct] [INFO ] [                ] [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] [org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start] - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-8040"] 
2022-07-21T10:39:43.780Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-0    ] - Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-07-21T10:39:48.787Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Cluster join: Retry 10: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-07-21T10:39:49.267Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 20 Elapsed 9.22 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2022-07-21T10:39:53.797Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-0    ] - Cluster join: Retry 15: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-07-21T10:39:54.278Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 30 Elapsed 14.23 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2022-07-21T10:39:58.807Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Cluster join: Retry 20: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-07-21T10:39:59.289Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 40 Elapsed 19.25 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2022-07-21T10:40:03.817Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-0    ] - Cluster join: Retry 25: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-07-21T10:40:04.300Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 50 Elapsed 24.26 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2022-07-21T10:40:08.827Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [67d49d906a9c2cc ] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Cluster join: Retry 30: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-07-21T10:40:09.310Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [86a7af00ba4ed81b] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 60 Elapsed 29.27 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
```

router-service.log: https://paste.opensuse.org/view/raw/39959906

Is there anything i can do to debug this issue? It seems that the router/broker/access service failed to start, but i cannot see any exception or a reason why.

Any clues, please?

Comment: Artifactory cannot connect to the Router service and fails to connect at 8046, can you check if the 8046 port is opened?  Also, share the router-service.log file here to see if there are any errors?

Comment: @MuhammedKashif I have edited my question with router-service.log output. Port 8046 is not opened (if you mean listening by opened). If you mean "allowed in firewall", then there is no local firewall running (iptables are empty).

Comment: @MuhammedKashif Maybe i am not starting the service correctly? All i do is `systemctl start artifactory`, but when i do, the contents of router-service.log are not updated. Should router-service be started with the "artifactory" systemd service or is there another service for that? I do not see that "router" is even starting from the logs. What am i missing?

Comment: the router should start as well but if it is not starting, I would suggest starting the service directly with 
"$JFrog_Home/artifactory/app/bin/artifactory.sh start" and see if it comes up?

Comment: @MuhammedKashif This is strange. With `sudo -u artifactory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactory.sh start`, it is starting correctly and everything works as expected. These are contents of the artifactory systemd unit file from debian package:
`[Unit]
Description=Artifactory service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=yes
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
PIDFile=/var/run/artifactory.pid
ExecStart=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start
ExecStop=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: @MuhammedKashif Ok, i tried launching it from both scripts and here are the results: `# /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactoryManage.sh start` (not working): [log](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/i8Gmbnpk/raw) `# sudo -u artifactory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/bin/artifactory.sh start` (working): [log](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/D91mG7FO/raw)

Comment: @MuhammedKashif Which means that there is a bug in the `artifactoryManage.sh` script that systemd uses? I don't know if this script is provided by Debian or JFrog to report it correctly. It just seems that the `artifactoryManage.sh` starts only tomcat itself and not the other required services.

Comment: artifcatoryManage.sh is managed by JFrog so you can reach the JFrog support on this.

Comment: I tested the installation of Artifactory in Debian 10.12 and it works for me as expected. Systemctl starts the Artifactory, ArtifactoryManage.sh works well and artifactory.sh works too.